# Tab character in shell giving different width

Tags: linux, shell, awk, formatting, whitespace

I want to ask that why this simple script gives different indentation 
If my way is wrong then please suggest the **right way**. :)

**datafile:**

```
Mr. James Adams General Manager
Mr. James Adams General Manager
Mr. James Carleo Branch Manager
Mr. James Cobb Branch Manager
Mr. James Collier Branch Manager
Mr. James K. Cross Sr.Vice
Mr. James Cummings Branch Manager
Mr. "James ""Jamie""" Dyer Branch
Mr. James (Danny) Farris Manager
Mr. James N. Martin General
Mr. James N. Martin General
Mr. James Ogden Branch Manager
Mr. James Wilson Branch Manager
```

**script:**

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,"\t",$4,$5}'
```

**expected output:**

```
Mr. James Adams      General Manager
Mr. James Adams      General Manager
Mr. James Carleo     Branch Manager
Mr. James Cobb       Branch Manager
Mr. James Collier    Branch Manager
Mr. James K.         Cross Sr.Vice
Mr. James Cummings   Branch Manager
Mr. "James ""Jamie"""    Dyer Branch
Mr. James (Danny)    Farris Manager
Mr. James N.         Martin General
Mr. James N.         Martin General
Mr. James Ogden      Branch Manager
Mr. James Wilson     Branch Manager
```

**actual output:**

```
Mr. James Adams      General Manager
Mr. James Adams      General Manager
Mr. James Carleo     Branch Manager
Mr. James Cobb   Branch Manager
Mr. James Collier    Branch Manager
Mr. James K.     Cross Sr.Vice
Mr. James Cummings   Branch Manager
Mr. "James ""Jamie"""    Dyer Branch
Mr. James (Danny)    Farris Manager
Mr. James N.     Martin General
Mr. James N.     Martin General
Mr. James Ogden      Branch Manager
Mr. James Wilson     Branch Manager
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pipe awk output with `column`:

```
awk '{print $1,$2,$3,"\t",$4,$5}' file|column -ts$'\t'
```

Comment: it worked, can you please explain how this is working ?

Comment: It is working but you accepted another answer :) You can read `man column` on the `-ts` options.

Comment: btw this answer avoids hardcoding the padding number unlike the other answer.

Comment: you are right this was the first correct solution, i have accepted yours solution. :)

Comment: Thanks for your acceptance, `column` is pretty useful utility.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `printf` in `awk` to adjust column width etc:

```
awk '{printf "%s %s %-20s %s %s\n",$1,$2,$3,$4,$5}' file
Mr. James Adams                General Manager
Mr. James Adams                General Manager
Mr. James Carleo               Branch Manager
Mr. James Cobb                 Branch Manager
Mr. James Collier              Branch Manager
Mr. James K.                   Cross Sr.Vice
Mr. James Cummings             Branch Manager
Mr. "James ""Jamie"""           Dyer Branch
Mr. James (Danny)              Farris Manager
Mr. James N.                   Martin General
Mr. James N.                   Martin General
Mr. James Ogden                Branch Manager
Mr. James Wilson               Branch Manager
```

Answer (score 2):

The tab character goes to the next tabstop after the current cursor Position.  That means the end point depents on the length of names already filtered.  If you want fixed-size fields I suggest you use `printf` to fix the size of the name column.  See http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Printf-Examples.html for documentation.

Answer (score 0):

(This is more of a comment, but I need the formatting available in an answer)

In the future, for this issue, make a "ruler" that will remind you where tab boundaries are, i.e.:

```
 #23457-1234567-1234567-1234567-1234567-1234567-1234567-..... as needed
```

So this shows you where your words will line up based on basic tabs.

As others above have pointed out, if you have a word is less that 8 chars long, 1 tab char will only take you to the position of the nearest tab char. You could cheat by adding extra spaces as needed in your input file and then you would need only 1 tab, but if you need data lining up per your example, then `printf` is your friend.

---

Good question, but your extra sample data obscured your problem. I was focusing first on the line

```
Mr. "James ""Jamie"""    Dyer Branch
```

2-3 lines of sample data and expected output from that sample data make issues easier to understand.